# Permission sets don't appear to take effect

Tags: profile, permission-sets, enterprise

Forgive me if this question is daft - my organization has just upgraded to Enterprise and I can't seem to get permissions to work the way I need them to.

I need to create permission sets that allow a specific set of staff to be able to see fields in various tabs (accounts, contacts, etc) however I want only a small portion of staff to be able to edit that data to ensure it's accuracy.

I don't believe we'll be utilizing the roles functionality as the landscape of the organization is not entirely hierarchal in a way that would benefit from this feature.

I created a profile and assigned it to a test user in a sandbox essentially providing access as to which Tabs are allowed, and read access to all of the fields they would need to see. I then tried to add a permission set on top of that to provide those select users the ability to edit required fields however the permission set never really seems to take effect. The user, even with the permission set assigned, is still only able to read all information but can't edit anything (even if their permission set allows it).

Can anyone provide some insight as to what I might be doing wrong here?

EDIT : I am aware of the Field Level Security functionality however this seems like it would be far more onerous as opposed to doing this with permission sets.

Comment: Permission Sets include Field Level Security, so you can't do one and ignore the other.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham so what you're saying is that in addition to setting "edit" properties to the fields I wish specific staff to be able to edit, that needs to be outlined too in Field Level Security? Is FLS not automatically "Edit" unless stated otherwise?

Comment: If you are setting viewable/editable properties on the fields, you are performing Field Level Security. This is separate from Create/Read/Edit/Delete rights on the object itself. Are you setting both of these things?

Answer (score 0):

Update:  If they only have read access via sharing settings you need to give modify all access in the Permission Set.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE @user11653! Typically this would get converted to a comment as not being an answer but I want to leave it until more feedback is received.

Comment: @user11653 Yes the permission state has "read' and "edit" on the permission set for the permission set I am attempting to create. It is not a VFpage but rather the normal Accounts page. Sharing settings are in fact allowing the permission to view the objects. The user is not the owner of a record in question but I would like them to be able to edit specific fields regardless of who the owner of the account is.

Comment: This might seem silly but did you make read and edit on the object in the permission set? If it is a VFpage, do they have access? To that separatly? 
Are your sharing settings giving access to view the objects? Even with the permission set OWD is in play. Is a hierarchy made? If so are they above the owner or is the record shared with them?